# Sharepoint 2010 Service Pack 2 + Language Packs

Tags: 2010, service-pack-2

Our test server currently contains SP1 + 5 SP1 language packs. Do we need to install SP2 (ENG/US) followed by 5 new language packs, such as the German one for instance.

400 MB in size though? How come all these Language Packs are the same size as the intial SP2 installation pack? I recall that these usually are around 30-40 MB for SP1. This means hours and hours of downtime if this ever goes to a production server.

Any feedback is much welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need the SP2 package for each language pack.  The product configuration wizard will fail if you have SP2 for SharePoint, but not the language packs.